# Sphinx search: Use OR option with attributes and text

Tags: sphinx

I need to get results from multiples queries with sphinx. There's no problem when there are only attribute conditions.

For example:

```
$this->cl->SetSelect ( "*, item_fkprogram=700 OR item_fkuser=350 AS mycond" );
$this->cl->SetFilter ( "mycond", array(1) );
$results=$this->cl->Query("","item");
```

It works fine, but sometimes I need to add text queries. For example:
Get items that:

```
Have item_fkprogram=700
OR Have item_fkuser=350
OR Have the search string "text1"
```

Can it be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can reduce pairs to a numerical value, you can use mva.

I explain

1° choose a value for each "param"
 - item_fkprogram  <- 00 
 - item_fkuser <- 01 
 - item_fkfoo <- 02

2 concat

so index like this

select id, 
CONCAT (item_fkprogram,'00,',item_fkuser,'01,',item_fkfoo,'02') AS orattr FROM table

and add

sql_attr_multi = uint orattr from field;

there you can search filter=sql_attr_multi,70000,35001

Another way is to transform values in "words" and use extended search

select id, 
CONCAT ('item_fkprogram',item_fkprogram,' ',
'item_fkuser',item_fkuser,' ',
'item_fkfoo',item_fkfoo) as xx  FROM table

search @xx "item_fkprogram700" "item_fkuser350"